# Infinite loading Grid is triggering loadMoreRows at the wrong time

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am using react-virtualized to build an **infinite loading grid**, which also uses `AutoSizer` to handle a dynamic grid width and `WindowScroller` to enable scrolling with the viewport. However, I am not able to successfully trigger `loadMoreRows` at the appropriate point in my infinite loading `Grid`.

I've narrowed down two things:

- When I set `columnCount` to 1 instead of 3 in my example below, the loading process seems to work as expected (ie. you scroll near the bottom, it loads another batch, it doesn't load again until we've completely loaded the previous batch).
- After you have accumulated about 40 rows (indicated at the top of my demo), you can't trigger `loadMoreRows()` unless you scroll up to an earlier row. To reproduce this behavior, scroll down until the grid has stopped loading new items at the bottom of the grid. Then try scrolling up and then back down again to see how it triggers `loadMoreRows()` somewhere earlier within the grid.

I put together a minimal plunker demo which will render a 3-column grid of random "lorem ipsum" text snippets. There is no end point for this example content, it just loads as much as you will scroll.

**Plunker Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/uoRdanlB1rXsgBe2Ej8i

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AutoSizer, CellMeasurer, CellMeasurerCache, Grid, InfiniteLoader, WindowScroller } from 'react-virtualized';

const MIN_BATCH_SIZE = 40;

// Return random snippet of lorem ipsum text
const randText = () => {
    const text = [
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
        'Consectetur adipisicing elit.',
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.',
        'Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
        'Ut enim ad minim veniam.',
        'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
        'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.',
        'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.',
        'Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
        'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.'
    ];

    return text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
};

// Cell data
const list = [];


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


// Infinite loading Grid that is AutoSize'd and WindowScroll'd with dynamic cell heights
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            columnWidth: 300,
            columnCount: 3,
            rowCount: 0,
            isLoading: false
        };

        this._cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
            fixedWidth: true,
            defaultHeight: 30
        });

        this._cellRenderer = this._cellRenderer.bind(this);
        this._isRowLoaded = this._isRowLoaded.bind(this);
        this._loadMoreRows = this._loadMoreRows.bind(this);
        this._onResize = this._onResize.bind(this);
        this._onSectionRendered = this._onSectionRendered.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ rowCount: 1 });
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        const { columnCount, rowCount } = this.state;

        if (rowCount !== nextState.rowCount) {
            if (nextState.rowCount > rowCount) {
                // Re-measure the row at the index which was last occupied by "loading" content
                for (let i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    this._cache.clear(this._lastLoadingIndex, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { columnCount, columnWidth, rowCount } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <h1 className="page-header lead">RV Infinite Grid</h1>

                <InfiniteLoader
                    isRowLoaded={this._isRowLoaded}
                    loadMoreRows={this._loadMoreRows}
                    rowCount={rowCount}
                    threshold={5}
                >
                    {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => {
                        this._onRowsRendered = onRowsRendered;

                        return (
                            <WindowScroller>
                                {({ height, scrollTop }) => (
                                    <AutoSizer
                                        disableHeight
                                        onResize={this._onResize}
                                    >
                                        {({ width }) => (
                                            <Grid
                                                autoHeight
                                                width={width}
                                                height={height}
                                                scrollTop={scrollTop}

                                                ref={grid => {
                                                    this._grid = grid;
                                                    registerChild(grid);
                                                }}

                                                columnWidth={columnWidth}
                                                columnCount={columnCount}

                                                rowCount={rowCount}
                                                rowHeight={this._cache.rowHeight}

                                                cellRenderer={this._cellRenderer}
                                                onSectionRendered={this._onSectionRendered}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    </AutoSizer>
                                )}
                            </WindowScroller>
                        );
                    }}
                </InfiniteLoader>
            </div>
        );
    }

    _isRowLoaded({ index }) {
        const { rowCount } = this.state;

        return index < rowCount - 1;
    }

    _loadMoreRows({ startIndex, stopIndex }) {
        const { isLoading } = this.state;
        const delay = 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000); // random delay to simulate server response time

        if (!isLoading) {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: true
            });

            setTimeout(() => {
                // Generate some new rows (for this example, we have no actual end point)
                for (let i = 0; i < MIN_BATCH_SIZE; i++) {
                    list.push([ randText(), randText(), randText() ]);
                }

                // Cancel the "loading" state and update the`rowCount`
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    rowCount: list.length + 1
                }, done);
            }, delay);

            let done;
            return new Promise(resolve => done = resolve);
        }
    }

    _cellRenderer({ key, rowIndex, columnIndex, parent, style }) {
        const { columnCount, columnWidth, rowCount } = this.state;
        let content;

        // Render cell content
        if (rowIndex < rowCount - 1) {
            const cellStyle = Object.assign({}, style, {
              backgroundColor: (rowIndex % 2 ? null : '#eee')
            });

            content = (
                <div style={cellStyle}>
                    <div style={{ padding: '20px' }}>
                        {list[rowIndex][columnIndex] || <em className="text-muted">empty</em>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

        // Render "loading" content
        else if (columnIndex === 0) {
            // Remember this `index` so we can clear its measurements from the cache later
            this._lastLoadingIndex = rowIndex;

            const cellStyle = Object.assign({}, style, {
              width: (columnWidth * columnCount), // Give loader the full grid width
              textAlign: 'center'
            });

            content = <div style={cellStyle}>Loading...</div>;
        }

        // Render empty cell (for incomplete rows)
        else {
            content = <div style={style} />;
        }

        return (
            <CellMeasurer
                key={key}
                cache={this._cache}
                parent={parent}
                columnIndex={columnIndex}
                rowIndex={rowIndex}
            >
                {content}
            </CellMeasurer>
        );
    }

    _onResize({ width }) {
        this.setState({
            // Subtracting 30 from `width` to accommodate the padding from the Bootstrap container
            columnWidth: (width - 30) / 3
        });

        this._cache.clearAll();
        this._grid.recomputeGridSize();
    }

    _onSectionRendered({ columnStartIndex, columnStopIndex, rowStartIndex, rowStopIndex }) {
        const { columnCount } = this.state;

        const startIndex = rowStartIndex * columnCount + columnStartIndex;
        const stopIndex = rowStopIndex * columnCount + columnStopIndex;

        this._onRowsRendered({
            startIndex,
            stopIndex
        });
    }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: This line is in your `_loadMoreRows` function is wrong: `rowCount: Math.ceil(list.length / columnCount) + 1`. It doesn't match the logic in the rest of your component. It should be: `rowCount: list.length + 1`. There seems to be something else going on here as well but I'm not yet sure what it is.

Comment: Thank you @brianvaughn for catching that mistake. I forgot to update that as I was adapting my real app to this minimal example. I updated my plunker demo with that line fixed. Indeed there is still an issue. I'll keep poking around and experimenting. Thanks :)

Comment: @brianvaughn I was able to answer my own question. I was providing the wrong range of rows to my `onRowsRendered` function.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question...

It turns out that my `_onSectionRendered` function was providing the wrong range to my `_onRowsRendered` function. I'll admit that I blindly copied and pasted the example snippet from the [InfiniteLoader docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md#infiniteloader-and-grid) into my own project until I understood more about it. It made sense to me at first to return the range of cells the way that it does in the docs, until I reminded myself that `InfiniteLoader` is looking at rows, not cells.

The example in the docs sets `startIndex` and `stopIndex` to a range of cells rather than returning the range of rows.

```
_onSectionRendered ({ columnStartIndex, columnStopIndex, rowStartIndex, rowStopIndex }) {
  const startIndex = rowStartIndex * columnCount + columnStartIndex
  const stopIndex = rowStopIndex * columnCount + columnStopIndex

  this._onRowsRendered({
    startIndex,
    stopIndex
  })
}
```

**To solve my issue**, I only pass `rowStartIndex` and `rowStopIndex` to `onRowsRendered()`.

```
onSectionRendered({ rowStartIndex, rowStopIndex }) {
  this._onRowsRendered({
    startIndex: rowStartIndex,
    stopIndex: rowStopIndex
  })
}
```

This is updated in my [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uoRdanlB1rXsgBe2Ej8i).

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying to use your example but the startIndex and stopIndex arguments of the _loadMoreRows function seem to be the same. Could you take a look at the following online example https://codesandbox.io/s/j497ko1m65?

Comment: Oh, guy. Thanks a lot. You really helped me.